# Combining multiple rows for each unique ID as a single row with multiple indexed column names in a view in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, window-functions, sql-view

In MS SQL Server 2016, I have a view, `vw_PERSON_COMPANY_CONTACT_INFO`, with the following columns:

```
,[COMPANY_ID]
,[PERSON_ID]
,[PERSON_NAME]
,[TITLE]
,[ADDRESS_ID]
,[ADDRESS_LINE_1]
,[ADDRESS_LINE_2]
,[ADDRESS_LINE_3]
,[CITY]
,[PROVINCE_STATE]
,[COUNTRY]
,[POSTAL_CODE]
,[EMAIL_ID]
,[EMAIL_ADDRESS]
,[PHONE_ID]
,[PHONE_NUMBER]
,[EXT]
```

Each row represents personal and contact information for individual employees. Some companies can have only a single employee, other a few dozens.

I would like to be able to create another view, `vw_COMPANY_CONTACTS`, combining all person/contact information (everything except `COMPANY_ID`, which would be shared by all entries in the row) as a single row per unique `COMPANY_ID` for the first 7 employees found. Each column name would potentially be renamed and incremented by an index starting with 1. As an example, I would have `ADDRESS_LINE_1` As `[Address1a]` for the first employee, As `[Address2a]` for the second, As `[Address3a]` for the third, etc.

What would be the most efficient way to create such view?

Comment: You do not want to create a view that selects from another view. This seems so logical but will absolutely cripple your performance. https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/performance/the-seven-sins-against-tsql-performance/#seven

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Sean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `rown_number()` and conditional aggregation.

The logic is like:

```
create view vw_COMPANY_CONTACTS as
select
    company_id,
    max(case when rn = 1 then person_id end) person_id_1,
    max(case when rn = 1 then title end) title_1,
    -- other columns for the contact n°1 go here
    max(case when rn = 2 then person_id end) person_id_2,
    max(case when rn = 2 then title end) title_2,
    -- other columns for the contact n°2 go here
from (
    select t.*, row_number() over(partition by company_id order by person_id) rn
    from vw_PERSON_COMPANY_CONTACT_INFO t
) t
group by company_id
```

Comment: This will work but nested views are terrible for performance. https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/performance/the-seven-sins-against-tsql-performance/#seven

Comment: I have used this logic without the used of the nested view and it works perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: @MiniG34: Sean Lange is correct, you should avoid nesting the views. It would be better to query directly the source table of the view.